# MooTools - return onSuccess variable in parent function

Tags: javascript, variables, mootools, xmlhttprequest, scope

Help me please! :(

How can I return the string by just using getValue()? I don't know how to apply the variable into the parent function. I'm getting headache:

```
<script>
    function getValue() {
        new Request.JSON({
            data: JSON.encode({
                "serviceName": "demoTest",
                "methodName": "someValue",
                "parameters": []
            }),
            onSuccess: function(data) { // data = a string with some text
                var string = data;
                console.log(string); // returns the string as expected
            },
            url: "gateway/?contentType=application/json"
        }).send();

        return string; // returns undefined
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `return` is fired long before the `onSuccess` (callback) function is triggered. One approach would be to use also a callback function. The way you want to do it won't work.

Here is your getValue function:

```
function setValue(callback) {
    new Request.JSON({
     ...
        onSuccess: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        },
    ....
}
```

Here is a callback function:

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
    $("id").set("html", "<p>" + data + "</p>");
}
```

And finally call the function on document loaded:

```
setValue(myCallback);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before and it works e.g. with alert(); but I need to return the value to parse it like this: $("id").set("html", "<p>" + getValue(); + "</p>");

Comment: the way you want to do it simply can't work. when calling getValue, the json request is running in an outside process. Therefore you can only access the response through a callback function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried something like that before, but it never worked. I tried your script in a simple simulation, because I'm not at the office right now, so I can't run the JSON Request but I will test it tomorrow.